# Using PCA on test set which has dimensionality less than number of principal components

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I've been working on a classification problem with a dataset that has 800 samples and 5000 features. I've used a dimensionality reduction technique such as PCA to reduce the dimensionality to around 120. This was done after I experimented with various no of principal components, and chose the number of principal components that captured the variance the most. I realize that the same principal components from the training stage must be used to transform the test set. However, I am confused about the situation where my test set has 100 samples and 5000 features. I realize the number of principal components cannot exceed 100(which is less than 120 chosen during the training stage)
(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28909/pca-when-the-dimensionality-is-greater-than-the-number-of-samples)

Should I be estimating the size of my test set with some certainty and then choosing my principal components during the training stage ? I was wondering if somebody could point me to literature or any other stackoverflow answer that deals with a similar problem. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: IIUC, you have 5000 features in both the test set and the training set. So it is possible to reduce the dimensionality to 120 in both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify and follow up on the previous comment: by "a dataset that has dimensionality around 800 x 5k" you mean that you have a dataset consisting of 5000 samples with 800 features each? If so, then your test set should have the same number of features, i.e. 800, as your training data set. Training and test data sets are created by randomly splitting samples, not features.

As an example, let's say you randomly split your dataset into a training dataset of 4000 samples and a test dataset of 1000 samples. You would then train PCA on the training data set to reduce the number of features from 800 to something like 120. The PCA learned on the training dataset would then be applied to the 1000 samples in your test data set to reduce the number of features from 800 to 120.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant that my training set has 800 samples with 5000 features. My test set has 100 samples, with similar 5000 features. However, if I use dimensionality reduction and reduce my dataset to 800 samples and 120 features (through PCA), I won't be able to do the same on the test set because the no of samples are less than the number of principal components.

Comment: On your test data, you can take the PCA components as given, so everything should work fine.
You could only compute up to 119 principal components using only the test data, but that's not what you're trying to do.

Comment: I realized my mistake. Thank you so much for clearing that up.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.